# Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant yet I'm not connected, and can't reach wpa_cli

Tags: arch-linux, wpa-supplicant, iw

i am trying to setup internet for my laptop currently running ArchLinux2017.07.01 but I ran into a big bump that I cannot seem to see anywhere else online. Mind you I am a little unfamiliar with Arch so I might be biting my tongue.

While following the wiki tutorial I get to this part
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Connect_to_an_access_point
Now Since my encryption is WPA2 I used the following given command

```
# wpa_supplicant -i interface -c <(wpa_passphrase "your_SSID" "your_key")
```

And output is:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
```

However when trying `# iw dev interface link` it says im not connected?

Even weirder, while trying to close wpa_supplicant via wpa_cli, I get the following error, following by infinite loading (unless aborted using CTRL+C):

```
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying
```

My question is this: what is going on and what can I do about it?
Feel free to ask for any information about my laptop setup, software etc if necessary.

Here is what I know:

- my networking controller drivers are installed, managed and able to scan
- the ssid and pass are 100% correct, I tested the same one on my other devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended method of connecting `wpa_cli` to `wpa_supplicant` is outlined [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli).

The issue is because your configuration does not provide `ctrl_interface`, which `wpa_cli` uses to interact with `wpa_supplicant`

You can run:

```
# wpa_supplicant -i interface -c <(wpa_passphrase "your_SSID" "your_key") -C /run/wpa_supplicant
```

however `wpa_cli` would only work under the `root` user.

A more complete way would be to create a config file like so:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="your_SSID"
    psk="your_key"
}
```

and running:

```
# wpa_supplicant -i interface -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/example.conf
```

This way, any user in the `wheel` group can access `wpa_cli`

Be sure to read the wiki on [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant)